# Can't perform HmacSHA256 hashing in Scala.js

Tags: scala, slack, hmac, scala.js, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to implement a method that will calculate & validate the HmacSHA256 signature for [verifying a slack request](https://api.slack.com/docs/verifying-requests-from-slack). For... various reasons... I'm using `scala.js`, and therefore I don't have access to the usual `javax.crypto` imports.

From slack's documentation on validating a signed request from Slack:

> - With the help of HMAC SHA256 implemented in your favorite programming, hash the above basestring, using the Slack Signing Secret
>     as the key.
> - Compare this computed signature to the X-Slack-Signature header on the request.

Well, the first step there is a problem. In scala.js, the `javax.crypto` package isn't available, so the following won't work:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac 
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

def asHmacSHA256(key: String, baseString: String): Array[Byte] = {
  val secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
  val hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
  hmac.init(secretKeySpec)
  hmac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes())
}
```

How can I work around this - is there a good hashing library that works with scala.js, or will I have to pull in some `js` dependency, or am I going to have to... *gulp*... roll my own hashing algorithm?

Comment: If you are happy with the js dependency, CryptoJS can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is one project that tends to do that (not sure about quality) https://github.com/fluencelabs/crypto. Internally it uses CryptoJS (and maybe using it directly will be even simpler or more stable way). But still you can see how it is used in fluencelabs/crypto.